# El uso del modo indicativo en las cláusulas condicionales en las cuales se usaba anteriormente el futuro del subjuntivo

Tags: gramática, verbos, subjuntivo, historia

Estudiaba los usos del futuro del subjuntivo, y leí unos frases con cláusulas condicionales. Sé que en el español de hoy, solemos usar el presente del subjuntivo en lugar del futuro. Pero, en estas cláusulas condicionales, es el presente del indicativo que reemplaza el futuro del subjuntivo.

Por ejemplo, en el español actual, podemos decir algo así:

> Si vienes a mi casa, te daré algo de pan.

Pero, por lo que entiendo, en el español antiguo diríamos:

> Si vinieres a mi casa, te daré algo de pan.

Este es un ejemplo que viene de la Biblia:

La RVR1960 dice:

> Si pecare el hombre contra el hombre, los jueces le juzgarán.

La Biblia de las Américas, que usa un español más actual, dice:

> Si un hombre peca contra otro, Dios mediará por él.

Lo que no entiendo es, ¿por qué usamos el presente del indicativo en lugar del futuro del subjuntivo en las cláusulas condicionales? Y, ¿cuándo ocurrió este cambio de modos?

Comment: Esta es una pregunta perfecta para guifa ; )

Comment: @fedorqui uf, lo es, pero no tengo el tiempo ahora mismo para escribir una respuesta detallada porque parto este finde para España y Portugal. Mas si en los próximos días tuviere un rato libre, contestarla he :-)

Comment: @guifa si a bien tuvieres de contestarla, contentos todos estaríamos. ¡Buen fin de semana tuvieres! ;-)

Comment: Me voy a aventurar a responder por mi cuenta y riesgo, a la espera de que @guifa tuviere a bien dar la suya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la nueva gramática de la lengua española, epígrafe 24.3c en la página 1814, tenemos lo siguiente:

> La forma CANTARE se usaba en las prótasis condicionales para enfatizar el valor hipotético de estas. La condición expresada se podía referir a hechos venideros [...] pero también a situaciones presentes. *Si ella fuere de tanta hermosura como significáis, de buena gana y sin apremio alguno confesaremos la verdad que por parte vuestra nos es pedida* (Cervantes, Quijote I).

Dado que la condición es sobre un hecho presente, resulta normal que, dado que el futuro de subjuntivo es un tiempo complicado, se simplificara su uso y se sustituyera por el presente de indicativo: *si ella es tan hermosa como decís...*

De hecho, en la propia gramática, en el epígrafe 24.3e, página 1814, se lee lo siguiente (negritas mías):

> El futuro simple de subjuntivo comenzó a perder su vitalidad a partir del siglo XIV, pero fue a partir de la segunda parte del siglo XVI cuando se redujo considerablemente su uso, hasta perder casi toda su vigencia en la época barroca. Sin embargo, siguió siendo común en la lengua escrita, sobre todo en algunas variedades regionales del español de América. Hasta entrado el siglo XX, los gramáticos siguieron recomendando su empleo para expresar lo contingente o conjetural. Poco a poco se fue sustituyendo por el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo, pero también por el **presente de indicativo**, hasta el punto de que ha caído hoy en desuso en la lengua oral de todas las áreas lingüísticas [...]

Imagino que la evolución fue simplemente una cuestión de simplificar el lenguaje.